# I can't install Docker because containerd.io has no installation candidate

Tags: docker, ubuntu

I tried to install Docker on Kubuntu 19.10.

I used these steps to install: https://docs.docker.com/install/linux/docker-ce/ubuntu/

During step 2, after added repository and key I got this message

```
Package containerd.io is not available, but is referred to by another package.
This may mean that the package is missing, has been obsoleted, or
is only available from another source

E: Package 'containerd.io' has no installation candidate
```

Answer (score 47, accepted):

It's not the cleanest way to do it I guess, but I had the same problem as you and I changed:

```
$ sudo add-apt-repository \
   "deb [arch=amd64] https://download.docker.com/linux/ubuntu \
   $(lsb_release -cs) \
   stable"
```

to

```
$ sudo add-apt-repository \
   "deb [arch=amd64] https://download.docker.com/linux/ubuntu \
   bionic \
   stable"
```

because

```
$(lsb_release -cs)
```

returns "eoan" (the name of the latest ubuntu version, currently 19.10) and it seems to cause problems.
Replacing this with "bionic" (ubuntu 18.10) worked perfectly for me, and I still have no problems 4 months later.

Don't forget to open "/etc/apt/sources.list" and comment-out/delete the line:

```
deb-src [arch=amd64] https://download.docker.com/linux/ubuntu eoan stable
```

to avoid conflicts.
 (You added this with the first command you entered in this process.)

Comment: Yes, this seems to be a bug. It has to be fixed in order for automatic updates

Answer (score 8):

Edit the file : **/etc/apt/sources.list**

Look for repo entry :

```
deb-src [arch=amd64] https://download.docker.com/linux/ubuntu eoan stable
```

Changing it to:

```
deb-src [arch=amd64] https://download.docker.com/linux/ubuntu bionic stable
```

resolved the issue for me

Answer (score 0):

The official docker  documentation recommend to use

```
  $ sudo add-apt-repository \
       "deb [arch=amd64] https://download.docker.com/linux/ubuntu \
       $(lsb_release -cs) \
       stable"
```

for **Ubuntu 19.10** which seems that doesn't contain 'containerd.io' package yet.

Remove the previously added repository using `add-apt-repository --remove` :

```
$ sudo add-apt-repository --remove \
       "deb [arch=amd64] https://download.docker.com/linux/ubuntu \
       $(lsb_release -cs) \
       stable"
```

and add the one used for bionic (18.10) Ubuntu release:

```
$ sudo add-apt-repository \
   "deb [arch=amd64] https://download.docker.com/linux/ubuntu \
   bionic \
   stable"
```

After this, update and install docker:

```
$ sudo apt-get update
$ sudo apt-get install docker-ce docker-ce-cli containerd.io
```

Answer (score 0):

If the from @vavalm did not work either, check that you have installed ubuntu amd64. There is a chance that you have installed the Ubuntu version i384 instead